# Displaying a video in C# with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#

Before I start, I'm using Visual Studio C# Ultimate 2010

I made a small WPF program which only displays a video when I click on a button.
When I click on my play button, the video is not displayed but on a friend's computer, it does.
With exactly the same code.
So I think it's a version problem, but I'm not sure.
I've checked the version of Visual Studio but we have the same.

Do you have an idea of solution?

Best regards,
Kevin

Comment: Codecs missing on your computer?

Comment: I just realised that my Windows Media Player displays that error message: Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, there might be codecs missing. This probably isn't a programming issue if it works on a friend's computer.

Use a tool like [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to find the codec used for that particular video file. You can then download the specific codec or, to avoid future codec issues, you might want to install something like [the K-Lite (Standard) Codec Pack](http://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_standard.htm) (but be sure the missing codec is part of the pack, of course).

A reboot shouldn't be necessary.